# iOS UIAutomation Can't access table view

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, ui-automation

I just started to test my app with UIAutomation. Which was going great! I wrote small javascript library so my tests are well written in code. But now after like 20 tests I need to access a row in a tableview.

This tableview is in a UIView which is set in loadView method. The tableview code is:

```
    _tableView.isAccessibilityElement = YES;
    _tableView.accessibilityValue = @"Menu";
```

But when I use the javascript function logElementTree(); It doesn't show up in the hierarchy? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `[self.view addSubview:_tableView]`?

Comment: This is just a short snippet of the complete code which instantiate the UITableView. The code works only the accessibility doesn't ;)

Comment: Which element are you using for `logElementTree()`? What do `mainWindow().tableViews()` or `mainWindow().logElementTree()` show?

Comment: I use mainWindow will test out the other one. As expected tableViews() is nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to set the accessibilityLabel to something. This is the property which is used to make it accessible